# Can anyone figure out how to update to flash_switcher.xpi to include Flash Player 10

Tags: firefox-addon, xpi, flashplayer-10

I don't know anything about XPIs but I've searched through the install.rdf, *.js, and *.xul files and found no reference to an array of flash versions, so I cannot clearly see where the version list comes from.

Comment: Hey could people vote to move this to SU? It didn't exist back then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out code changes are not required; I just added the correct files to the plugins folder. I also had to rename the other plugin folder names to keep it about ordered.

So I've added the v10 Flash Player for Windows and Linux to the [flash switcher xpi](http://www.box.net/shared/fmghgzlaey) and those of you who need can download it there. It's in a 3 part zip.